# Добавление приложения в "Open With" диалог Android

Tags: java, android

Мое приложение работает с базами данных SQLite, хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь мог увидеть мое приложение в диалоге "Открыть с помощью" при попытке открытии базы даных в файловой системе. Как реализовать такое?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<activity name="com.your.activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.sqlite" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

вместо `\\.sqlite` можете поставить любое другое расширение файла.

И дальше в классе Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();  
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)){
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            new File(uri.getPath()); //дальше делаем все, что надо с файлом 
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "intent was something else: "+action);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как понимаю, код нужно вставлять в начало главного активити?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в манифесте настроить интент-фильтр на расширение вашей базы ( либо на mime-тип )

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  <data android:pathPattern="*.*\\.db" />
</intent-filter>
```

[подробности](http://%3Cintent-filter%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Caction%20android:name=%22android.intent.action.VIEW%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccategory%20android:name=%22android.intent.category.DEFAULT%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccategory%20android:name=%22android.intent.category.BROWSABLE%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdata%20android:mimeType=%22*/*%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdata%20android:pathPattern=%22*.*%5C%5C.kdb%22%20/%3E%20%3C/intent-filter%3E)